# How to configure SourceSwitch in appsettings.json for .Net 5.0 applicaiton?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I wanted to configure source switches in appsettings.json file for my .Net 5.0 application.
In [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.sourceswitch?view=net-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) it only shows how to do in XML configuration file, that my application is not using.

My application is console application that is installed as Widnows Service and is using appsettings.json file for configuration.

**What I want to achieve.**

I want to be able to log to Trace `Trace.WriteLine(...)` for entire application and have level configured in appsettings.json.

**Parts of Code**

Here is how I initialize it next to rest of DI initialization: `logging.AddTraceSource("GlobalSwitch");`

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. There's no app.config, web.config, trace sources or SourceSwitch any more. Both configuration and logging are different. Check [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), especially the [Configure Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging) section

Comment: Also note that appsettings.json is just one of the possible configuration sources. [.NET Core's configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can use multiple sources, including multiple file formats, databases, environment variables, the command line etc. `appsettings.json` is used only if it's explicitly added as a source. The default Generic Host uses appsettings,environment variables and cli parameters which means you can easily override logging settings by setting an environment variable or a cli parameter

Comment: `My application is console application that is installed as Widnows Service` consider creating a [new worker service project deployed as a Windows Servicet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/net-core-workers-as-windows-services/) if only to check the differences between .NET Old and .NET Core. The project template sets up the generic host with config, logging, DI and adds a [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) class to handle the actual processing.

Comment: The same project can be deployed on Linux simply by using `UseSystemd` instead of `UseWindowsService` in the Startup configuration

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos - This is exactly what I have done. But I would like to be able to write to Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine so I can run dbgview in case I need to check something.

Comment: For starters, the [logging&tracing section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing) explains how to use low-level tracing like `Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine`, in the [Print style APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing#print-style-apis) section. That's the most primitive alternative. High perf event based tracing is provided by the [EventSource and DiagnosticSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing#logging-events) classes. You can also use the debugger output as a logging sink

Comment: Debug output is one of the default loggers configured by the Hosting infrastructure, so you already have it. That's why you see log messages in the Output window while debugging. If you use another library, like Serilog, you may want to use its own sink, like Serilog.Sinks.Debug. There are some ILogger implementations useful for testing, like [DebugLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.debug.debuglogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2) and NullLogger (which logs nothing).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see this System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.
But how to make it so it will write to Trace.WriteLine? I have no idea how to configure in my HostBuilder method to make it so. Can you help me with this?

Comment: `Trace.WriteLine` was never a trace *target*. Even in .NET Old, calling `Trace.WriteLine` doesn't write to the debug output directly. It sends its payload to any configured target (listener), like a file, the console or the debug output. The targets are configured either programmatically or app.config. I suspect you assumed `Trace.WriteLine` wrote to the debug output because that's one of the default targets in debug builds.

Comment: Besides, EventSource isn't meant for low-level print statements. It's meant for high-perf, near-real time event publishing. Printing text is the exact opposite of high-perf. If you want to print strings, use the logging infrastructure. With EventSource, .NET itself and applications publish events specified only by their Ids and contain only event properties, not explanatory text. The text is produced by the event consumers. Unlike logging or `WriteLine`, the overhead is minimal if there are no listeners, as no strings are allocated or garbage collected